# What book has a virus-maddened post-apocalyptic beer run?

Tags: story-identification, horror, post-apocalyptic, soft-sci-fi

Ok. This is going to be a task.

The years of this book can be anywhere from 1991-1995.

I remember the following about this novel:

1. It was a one shot. It wasn't a series.
2. It was a pre/post apocalypse tale about people going crazy from a virus
3. A comic book writer wrote this. (Thought it was Peter David but no.. not him)
4. Supposedly there was a beer run involved (I think)

Any ideas? I really want to find, read and OWN this book again!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please take a look through [these](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [checklists](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) and see if anything there jogs your memory. You probably remember details that you don't even know you remember - you just need to ask yourself the right questions.

Comment: Was it a natural virus, or was it a weapon created by a government or a terrorist organization or an independent mad scientist or extraterrestrials?

Comment: "Looking for a book" describes hundreds of questions on this site. I changed the title to something more descriptive. If you can think of a better title, use the edit button at the bottom of your question to change it.

Comment: Sounds like Shaun of the Dead, but not a book of course.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be Steve Wilson's *[The Lost Traveler](https://mcsmith187.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/the-lost-traveler-by-steve-wilson/)*?

[image: The Lost Traveler book cover]

> In the third year of the last decade of the twentieth century which is a fancy way for the author to say 1993, civilization came to an end. For reasons lost to time the world powers launched an all out attack devastating the world with nuclear, chemical and biological attacks. This event became known as BLAM. Now after the BLAM those most used to the absence of civilization were in the best position to survive and the Hell’s Angel Motorcycle Club Los Angeles chapter were survivors. **A group on a beer run manage to save the President of the United State** from looters. The Angels offer their services as bodyguards which the President accepts. Thus with the President using the Hell’s Angels as a Preatorian Guard and some academics form the Fief in the San Joaquim Valley. A rival group forms the Peregrine Fief further west and uses a rival motorcycle gang the Gypsy Jokers as their enforcers.

I don't see a virus listed as an aspect of the apocalypse, but it does mention the use of biological weapons, and part of the plot is rescuing a scientist who can make the "dead lands" inhabitable, which might suggest something with a virus (although other descriptions do make it sounds more like the problem is nukes/radiation):

> A scientist working for them has discovered a process to make the dead lands habitable. The Fief sends three Hell’s Angels lead by Long Range and his buddy Milt and another Angel named Belial. Linking up with Indians fighting the Federation they infiltrate the complex in the Ozark Mountains to rescue the scientist.

Lastly, while I can't swear it's the same guy, there is a [Steve Wilson](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Wilson) who was a writer for DC. There are some other covers and a review with slightly different details [here](http://www.apocalypsebooks.com/books/the-lost-traveller/).